# What do you call the curved strip magnets in Hall Effect twist throttles?

Tags: magnets

Many twist throttles (for e-bikes, etc.) have long thin curved magnets read by a Hall Effect sensor.  I want to buy some but I don't know what they're called.
[image]

To clarify, this magnet is read by a single analog Hall Effect sensor to provide the rotational position of the twist grip.  Don't overthink it.

Comment: maybe `shaped magnet` ... are you sure that it is a magnet?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a magnetic encoder that uses hall sensors rather than "just a hall sensor and magnet"? Because encoders don't use regular old magnetic strips. Magnetic strips used by encoders are graduated or have other magnetic delineations on them and the sensor and strip are specifically made to work together as a pair.

Comment: @DKNguyen, any I've seen have been analog out.

Comment: @Transistor I've seen both analog output and digital output magnetic encoders. No idea what motorcycles use though.

Comment: I have seen it referred to as a "tape" and as a "strip" along with other words like magnetic and encoder.  Make sure it is for measurement as opposed to sticking something on a fridge, and mind that not all tapes and sensors are compatible- spacing and rate at which you provide it to the sensor can affect necessary electronics.